# Python Printing the String Result

Tags: python, string, printing

```
import operator

def mkEntry(file1):
    results = []
    for line in file1:
        lst = line.rstrip().split(",")
        lst[2] = int(lst[2])
        results.append(lst)
    return print(sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2)))


def main():
    openFile = 'names/' + 'yob' + input("Enter the Year: ") + '.txt'
    file1 = open(openFile)
    mkEntry(file1)

main()
```

File:

```
Emily,F,25021
Emma,F,21595
Madison,F,20612
Olivia,F,16100
Joaquin,M,711
Maurice,M,711
Kade,M,701
Rodrigo,M,700
Tate,M,699
```

How do I print out the result looks like this:
1. Name (Gender): Numbers
Instead of ['name', 'gender', numbers]

I have trouble doing the string thing. It won't give me the good output. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return print(sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2)))` isn't doing what you'd expect it to.

Because `print()` returns `None`, your function will `return None`. Get rid of the print statement (if you want to print the line, just put it before the return)

Then you can do in your `main()` function:

```
for person in mkEntry(file1):
    print("1. {0} ({1}): {2}".format(*person))
```

Comment: I fixed it. I did that, it prints this: `['Shelly', 'F', 975]` instead of `1. Shelly (F): 975`

Comment: @Singh2013 It's from the for-loop: `for person in mkEntry(file1)`. It's like what you did at `for line in file1:`

Comment: How do I do the numbers? like this? `print("{0}. {1} ({2}): {3}".format(count, results[0], results[1]. results[2]))`

Comment: @Singh2013 Yup! Or `.format(count, *results)`. The `*` *unpacks* the list. It's the same as if you individually typed it as you showed